# I can't stop myself from masturbation

Tags: masturbation

I started masturbation its been a Quite long time. Once my mom saw 18+ videos on my phone I was really ashamed and shamed she told me to never watch it Again I Didn't for a long time. But in this world where social media shows Everything and in movies there is scenes that makes me really active and i can't control.  I'm 23 years old I have sexual needs I'm a student I can't marry now and I need to somehow full fill my needs.  So how can i stop? I can't leave social media,  I love watching movies and series also i can't stop my eyes looking at women who wears short and tight cloths how can i stop myself I Don't understand.  Why i was born in this generation why? I'm Ashamed also I can't stop myself what to do I feel guilty

Comment: There are many men in a situation similar to yours: trying to quit the habit but struggling. Have you tried looking for online programs, courses, or communities to help with specifically this challenge? For example, see https://swproject.co.uk/swcourses/

Answer (score 0):

aha, repent to allah, know with proof that Allah does forgive you, then move on from those sins, next find happiness in your goals, ask yourself, is watching films, movies, and everything else, really helping you achieve anything or is it just delusion, start working for what can have an impact, you can be whoever you want to be, just find that potential that is already in you, and u can do that by imagining where you see yourself, what you want from life, and how u can reach there, plan and then stop fearing that u won't be able to get there, the journey becomes worthwhile, if the outcome is guaranteed, so find the outcome ur happy with and go for it.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't masturbate for long time, you will eventually masturbate in dreams (nocturnal emission). No body says nocturnal emission is forbidden. If something is allowed in dreams, how it can be forbidden when awake. There are early scholars who said that there is nothing wrong in masturbation, they have said it is your liquid you can throw it away anytime. Some medical experts have said if masturbation is done excessively it can effect normal sexual relationship.

> Let those who find not the wherewithal for marriage keep themselves
> chaste, until Allah gives them means out of His grace. [Quran
> 24:33](https://quran.com/24/33)

So we have to abstain from fornication at all cost.

Comment: Some people fornicate in their dreams. Can they also fornicate while awake? How can it be forbidden?

Comment: nocturnal emission is real ejaculation itself, even though the things imagined is in dream.  But if you do real fornication in sleep it is haraam and the person is responsible for it and such situations should be avoided.