# My Brother had sex with some item but not human will it count as zina

Tags: zina

My brother who is very kind to people . Have some family problem going up . He is not technically my own blood brother . But my cousin brother. One day I saw him with a pillow inside of his pants and he was having sex with it. I don't know anything about this . He not to tell anybody. Will this count as a zina?. What if he asked for forgiveness from Allah. Will he go to paradise .

Answer (score 0):

If there is no woman involved then it is only masturbation. There are difference of opinion on whether masturbation is allowed or not.  see my answer to this question [I can't stop myself from masturbation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/81491/i-cant-stop-myself-from-masturbation/81496#81496)